# How to pass NULL instead of string format 'NULL' value using XML node in SQL server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, xmlnode

I'm using XML node() method to extract XML data using SQLSserver 2008.

Now while extracting the XML data, one of the integer data type of XML field have a value like NULL and It is trying to insert as string format 'NULL' instead of NULL.

below is XML Node() query to extract data,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WO_Log](
[Flag] [int] NULL,
[FillingPO] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PackAtCAN1] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

declare @message XML

set @message='<ProductionOrder>
          <Header>
            <MessageID>00000005</MessageID>
            <PublishedDate>2013-05-30 09:30:10</PublishedDate>
          </Header>
          <Body>
            <ProductionOrderDetails>
              <Flag>NULL</Flag>
              <FillingPO>NULL</FillingPO>
              <PackAtCAN1>NULL</PackAtCAN1>
            </ProductionOrderDetails>
          </Body>
        </ProductionOrder>'


 INSERT INTO dbo.WO_Log(Flag,FillingPO,PackAtCAN1)
  SELECT p.value('Flag[1]','int')
         p.value('FillingPO[1]','NVARCHAR(50)'),
         p.value('PackAtCAN1[1]','BIT')
  FROM  @message.nodes('/ProductionOrder/Body/ProductionOrderDetails') x(p)

 Now when I'm execute the query i'm getting the error as below,
```

> "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cast in the xQuery for `value()`. It will return NULL if the cast fails.

```sql
SELECT p.value('Flag[1] cast as xs:int?','int'),
       p.value('FillingPO[1]','NVARCHAR(50)'),
       p.value('PackAtCAN1[1] cast as xs:boolean?','BIT')
FROM  @message.nodes('/ProductionOrder/Body/ProductionOrderDetails') x(p)
```

[Type Casting Rules in XQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191231.aspx)

If you want to get `NULL` for the string value `'NULL'` in a character node you can use `isnull` on the result from `value()`.

```
SELECT p.value('Flag[1] cast as xs:int?','int'),
       nullif(p.value('FillingPO[1]','NVARCHAR(50)'), N'NULL'),
       p.value('PackAtCAN1[1] cast as xs:boolean?','BIT')
FROM  @message.nodes('/ProductionOrder/Body/ProductionOrderDetails') x(p)
```